# REGEXP от слова до слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения

На странице есть несколько вот таких кусков:

```
notice":true,"user_can_reopen_ticket":true,"recipient_id":"None","fulfillment_min_raw":1547416736,"status":"Shipped","fulfillment_max_yearless":"Feb 25","ticket_perm_closed":false,"merchant_price":1.0,"delivered"
```

Как вытащить с помощью регулярки только `"merchant_price":1.0`,

Важно, что кусок должен начинаться с notice":true ( то, что после notice":true, и до merchant_price может отличаться.. )

Comment: взять полноценный json и декодировать его уже не модно?

Comment: Наверное у поля `"merchant_price"` значение `1.0` тоже меняется?

Answer (score 0):

Вот `(.*),("merchant_price":.*),(.*)` ([тест](https://regex101.com/r/xTlfMC/1)) . Группа 2 ($2) будет нужное вам значение